How to Solve Conversion Error between LPWSTR and char Array with GetModuleFileName
I use a char array as the second parameter when calling the GetModuleFileName function, but I expect a value of type LPWSTR
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

std::string generateRandomName(const std::vector<std::string>& possibleNames) {
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(0)));
    int randomIndex = std::rand() % possibleNames.size();
    return possibleNames[randomIndex];
}

void renameFile() {
    std::vector<std::string> possibleNames = { "steam", "afterfx", "chrome", "discord", "svchost", "brave", "photoshop", "operagx", "explorer"};
    std::string randomFileName = generateRandomName(possibleNames);

    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(nullptr, /*ERRRRORRRRR>>>>*/ **buffer** , MAX_PATH);
    std::string currentExecutable = buffer;

    std::string newFileName = randomFileName + ".exe";

    if (std::rename(currentExecutable.c_str(), newFileName.c_str()) == 0) {
        std::cout << "";
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "";
    }
}


So make them match? As written, the solution appears known to you and within your control.

Does this answer your question? C++ Convert string (or char*) to wstring (or wchar_t*)

Sounds like your application uses wide characters. So, use those everywhere. Use wchar_t for your buffer, and std::wcout. Or change your project's character type. Or perform string conversions. Or use GetModuleFileNameA.
